# How to make a request to the Intersango API

Tags: python, httprequest

I'm trying to figure out what's the correct URL format for the [Intersango API](https://bitcoinconsultancy.com/wiki/Intersango/API) (which is poorly documented). I'm  programming my client in C#, but I'm looking at the [Python example](https://bitcoinconsultancy.com/wiki/Intersango/API/python) and I'm a little confused as to what is actually being placed in the body of the request:

```
def make_request(self,call_name,params):
    params.append(('api_key',self.api_key)) // <-- How does this get serialized?
    body = urllib.urlencode(params) 

    self.connect()

    try:
        self.connection.putrequest('POST','/api/authenticated/v'+self.version+'/'+call_name+'.php')
        self.connection.putheader('Connection','Keep-Alive')
        self.connection.putheader('Keep-Alive','30')
        self.connection.putheader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        self.connection.putheader('Content-length',len(body))
        self.connection.endheaders()

        self.connection.send(body)

        response = self.connection.getresponse()

        return json.load(response)
//...
```

I can't figure out this piece of code: `params.append(('api_key',self.api_key))`

Is it some kind of a dictionary, something that gets serialized to JSON, comma delimited, or exactly how does it get serialized? What would the body look like when the parameters are encoded and assigned to it?

P.S. I don't have anything that I can run the code with so I can debug it, but I'm just hoping that this is simple enough to understand for somebody that knows Python and they would be able to tell me what's happening on that line of code.

Comment: have you been able to make it work? I followed the same steps, but cannot get authenticated API work at all, getting {"The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation Failed."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is a list of 2-element lists. The list would look like ((`key1, value1), (key2, value2), ...)`

`params.append(('api_key',self.api_key))` adds another 2-element list to the existing params list.

Finally, `urllib.urlencode` takes this list and converts it into a propert urlencoded string. In this case, it will return a string `key1=value1&key2=value2&api_key=23423`. If there are any special characters in your keys or values, urlencode will %encode them. See [documentation for urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the C# code working, and it kept failing with exception {"The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation Failed."}. I finally found what the problem is. You could read about it in depth [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx)

In short, the way to make C# access Intersango API is to add following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

This code needs to only run once. This is a global setting, so it affects your full application, so beware that something else could break as a result.

Here's a sample code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
var address = "https://intersango.com/api/authenticated/v0.1/listAccounts.php";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("api_key=aa75***************fd65785");
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake 
instead of `params.append(('api_key',self.api_key))`
just write:

```
params['api_key']=self.api_key
```